# org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file while trying to read a .csv file using poi

Tags: java, excel-2007, apache-poi

INFO: Server startup in 1778 ms
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Temp\poifiles\poi-ooxml--2049907849.tmp'
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:102)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:155)
    at com.web.controller.ExcelReader.processUploadedFile(ExcelReader.java:83)
    at com.web.controller.ExcelReader.doPost(ExcelReader.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: I had the same issue, changed the read/write permission to C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Temp\poifiles, it worked.
as @Gagravarr mentioned, I was using the .xls file. Not .csv format.

Comment: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/InvalidOperationException-Can-t-open-specified-file-td5524067.html it may help someone

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI can only read Excel .xls (via HSSF) and Excel .xslx (via XSSF). It cannot open CSV files

To work with CSV files, you'll need to use another library. Alternately, if you save your file as a .xls or .xlsx, you can then use Apache POI to process it.